# Set the installer Properties in Deferred C# custom action

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield

In a **C# custom action** function,e xecuting in **deferred mode**, property values can be accessed using "CustomActionData" property. Requirement is that the same action function also need to set few msi property values. What are the ways in which C# deferred custom action function can set the values to the properties.

If custom action run in immediate , direct method is :
`session["PropertyName"]="PropertyValue";`

How to achieve the same in deferred custom action?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set properties in deferred execution. The deferred custom action can only access it's CustomActionData property.

You should schedule an immeadiate custom action prior to the deferred custom action.  In this ca you should read whatever tables and properties that you need to, apply any business logic nessecary and that set a property with the same name as the deferred custom action.   The deferred custom action will then see this as CustomActionData.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions